# Assign a variable to "label" type, or how to type cast between pointers

Tags: go, types, interface, casting

I have two identical structures, which for disambiguation purposes have different types:

```
type BaseType struct {
   id  uint64
   name string
}

type LabeledType1 BaseType
type LabeledType2 BaseType
```

There is one function in the whole chain which actually doesn't care about the `LabeledType`, it just works with the `BaseType` (because it does the exact same thing with both). The sender of the event has to send the labeled type, not the base type, because the actual type defines some post-behavior.

```
func handle(evt interface{}) error {
  switch e := evt.(type) {
  case *LabeledType1: 
    return handleBaseEvent(e)
  case *LabeledType2:
    return handleBaseEvent(e)
  //there are other types
  case *OtherType:
      return handleOtherType(e)
  } 
}

func handleBaseEvent(evt *BaseType) {
   //do stuff
}
```

Now of course this doesn't compile:

```
cannot convert e (type *LabeledType1) to type BaseType
```

But I wonder, both types are **assignable** as far as I understand that concept, so there should be some easy conversion? I've tried type casting:

`evt.(BaseType)`)

and also

`BaseType(e)`

I can't use a `bool` inside `BaseType`.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to use this as a form of polymorphism, which it is not. What are you actually trying to accomplish? There is likely a better/more idiomatic way to accomplish it in Go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `(*BaseType)()` [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to convert a `*LabeledType1` and `*LabeledType2` to a `*BaseType`:

```
func handle(evt interface{}) error {
    switch e := evt.(type) {
    case *LabeledType1:
        return handleBaseEvent((*BaseType)(e))
    }
    ...
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lhvW2Y2Hk_X).

Comment: yes!!! that's it, I had tried `BaseType(e)` but that is a mismatch between a pointer and a struct, but didn't know how to achieve it for a pointer :) Thanks!

Comment: I have edited the question title so that it is a bit clearer what I was actually requesting :)